# How to split string if different character occur?

Tags: java, string

I have a string like below:

```
String str = "77755529";
```

I want to split this string if different number occur i.e result should be like below after splitting :

```
str1 = "777";
str2 = "555";
str3 = "2";
str4 = "9";
```

I tried it with split but could not make it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
String   str = "77755529";
String[] res = str.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");
```

**[IDEONE SAMPLE](https://ideone.com/MyvsA7)**

Answer (score 2):

You may do matching.

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\1+|\\d+").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
   lst.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(lst);
```